# Enabling / Disabling Specific Row Values

Tags: php, jquery, forms, html-table, row

I've created a form that is being populated from a database.

The results appear on screen and by default I disable all the form fields except the initial dropdown list on each row.

Changing the value of the dropdown list should enable or disable the form fields on that specific row. This works for the first row only, but not the subsequent rows.

I think this is because I'm only referencing the first row, but I'm to sure how to change this..

This what I've got so far.. bare in mind this is only 2 rows, the live data could present lots of rows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#option').change(function(){
          if($(this).val()=="2"){
            $("#name").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#id").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#home").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#active").removeAttr("disabled");
          }

          if($(this).val()!="2"){
            $("#name").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#home").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#active").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='usr' method='post' action='test.php'>
        <table border='1' width='60%'>
            <tr>
                <th>Val1</th>
                <th>Val2</th>
                <th>Val3</th>
                <th>Val4</th>
                <th>Val5</th>
                <th>Val6</th>
            </tr>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td>
                    <select name='option' id='option' />
                        <option></option>
                        <option value='1'>Option1</option>
                        <option value='2'>Option2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>USR1</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='name[]' id='name' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='id[]' id='id' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name='home[]' id='home' disabled='disabled'/>
                        <option value='North'>North</option>
                        <option value='South'>South</option>
                        <option value='Other'>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='active[]' id='active' disabled='disabled'/>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='2'>No</option>
                        <option value='3'>Dead</option>
                        <option value='4'>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align='center'>
                <td>
                    <select name='option' id='option' />
                        <option></option>
                        <option value='1'>Option1</option>
                        <option value='2'>Option2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>USR2</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='name[]' id='name' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='id[]' id='id' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name='home[]' id='home' disabled='disabled'/>
                        <option value='North'>North</option>
                        <option value='South'>South</option>
                        <option value='Other'>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='active[]' id='active' disabled='disabled'/>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='1' >Yes</option>
                        <option value='2' >No</option>
                        <option value='3' >Dead</option>
                        <option value='4'>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can some one help me to get this to work for all rows. When selecting the dropdown at the beginning of a row it should affect that row only.

Comment: All your form fields have the same `name` and `id`. You have no way of distinguishing between them, so the browser defaults to the _first_. This is the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks thats what I assumed.. As this is coming from a DB I can add the count to each id, so they would become `name1`, `id1`, `name2`, `id2` etc. But how do I reference them in jquery ?

Comment: This is the part that jQuery isn't very good at. There are workarounds but they're all pretty nasty. You could try and find some examples of how other people with dynamically generated data/forms.

Comment: OK, I was hoping I could get the row ID and then use that to manipulate the row..

Comment: Yea, you can probably do that, looks for other solutions that do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorted.**

using the change with a class and getting the row id, then prefixing that to the id lookup used to add or remove the disabled.

Each id='name', id='id' are being updaed from the DB so they now appear as `name1, id1, name2, id2.`

Thanks to **George** for the mention of Class.

Example below..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.option').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;

    if($(this).val()=="2"){
     $("#name"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#id"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#home"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#active"+id).removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    if($(this).val()!="2"){
    $("#name"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#id"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#home"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#active"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id='usr' method='post' action='test.php' ><table border='1' width='60%'><tr><th>Val1</th><th>Val2</th><th>Val3</th><th>Val4</th><th>Val5</th><th>Val6</th></tr>

<tr align='center'>
<td><select name='option' class='option' /><option></option><option value='1'>Option1</option><option value='2'>Option2</option></select></td>
<td>USR1</td>
<td><input type='text' name='name[]' id='name1' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
<td><input type='text' name='id[]' id='id1' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
<td><select name='home[]' id='home1' disabled='disabled'/><option value='North'>North</option><option value='South'>South</option><option value='Other'>Other</option></select></td>
<td><select name='active[]' id='active1' disabled='disabled'/><option value=''></option><option value='1' >Yes</option><option value='2' >No</option><option value='3' >Dead</option><option value='4'>Other</option></select></td>
</tr>

<tr align='center'>
<td><select name='option' class='option' /><option></option><option value='1'>Option1</option><option value='2'>Option2</option></select></td>
<td>USR2</td>
<td><input type='text' name='name[]' id='name2' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
<td><input type='text' name='id[]' id='id2' value='' disabled='disabled'/></td>
<td><select name='home[]' id='home2' disabled='disabled'/><option value='North'>North</option><option value='South'>South</option><option value='Other'>Other</option></select></td>
<td><select name='active[]' id='active2' disabled='disabled'/><option value=''></option><option value='1' >Yes</option><option value='2' >No</option><option value='3' >Dead</option><option value='4'>Other</option></select></td>
</tr>

</form></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK first you'd better you `class` instead of `id` because `id`. I've build Fiddle with working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9EfvS/

And here is the code:

12 adn 314 is conditional and would mean entry unique id (better use it instead of just row count 1,2,3 etc..) because it's easier after posting to the server to compare with database entries

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.blah').change(function () {

    var parentTR = $(this).parents('tr');
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        $(parentTR).find(".name").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".id").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".home").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".active").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    if ($(this).val() != "2") {
        $(parentTR).find(".name").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".home").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(parentTR).find(".active").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    });
});


<form id='usr' method='post' action='test.php'>
<table border='1' width='60%'>
    <tr>
        <th>Val1</th>
        <th>Val2</th>
        <th>Val3</th>
        <th>Val4</th>
        <th>Val5</th>
        <th>Val6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align='center'>
        <td>
            <select name='option[12]' id='option12' class='blah' />
            <option></option>
            <option value='1'>Option1</option>
            <option value='2'>Option2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>USR1</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='name[12]' class='name' value='' disabled='disabled' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='id[12]' class='id' value='' disabled='disabled' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name='home[12]' class='home' disabled='disabled' />
            <option value='North'>North</option>
            <option value='South'>South</option>
            <option value='Other'>Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name='active[12]' class='active' disabled='disabled' />
            <option value=''></option>
            <option value='1'>Yes</option>
            <option value='2'>No</option>
            <option value='3'>Dead</option>
            <option value='4'>Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align='center'>
        <td>
            <select name='option[314]' id='option314' class='blah' />
            <option></option>
            <option value='1'>Option1</option>
            <option value='2'>Option2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>USR1</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='name[314]' class='name' value='' disabled='disabled' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='id[314]' class='id' value='' disabled='disabled' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name='home[314]' class='home' disabled='disabled' />
            <option value='North'>North</option>
            <option value='South'>South</option>
            <option value='Other'>Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name='active[314]' class='active' disabled='disabled' />
            <option value=''></option>
            <option value='1'>Yes</option>
            <option value='2'>No</option>
            <option value='3'>Dead</option>
            <option value='4'>Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</form>
```